# Is there a cleaner way to print a coordinate system?

Tags: c

So I need to print a coordinate system, and here is what I've done

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main() {
        int n, x, y;
        do {
            printf("Enter the size: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            printf("Enter coordinates (x,y): ");
            scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
            for( int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++ ) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("^\n");
            for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                for( int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++ ) {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                printf("|\n");
            }
            printf("<");
            for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                printf("-");
            }
            printf("+");
            for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                printf("-");
            }
            printf(">\n");
            for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                for( int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++ ) {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                printf("|\n");
            }
            for( int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++ ) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("v\n");


        } while( n != 0 );

    }
```

also, I need to print "*" on the coordinates, so if someone can help with that also, I would appreciate it.
If I enter 5 it should look like <-----+-----> and in the middle same size but vertical, it looks good, but is there a way to make it cleaner, and how do I put "*" in the spot of (x,y) coordinates I enter

Comment: What exactly is "a coordinate system" in this context? Please give more details including example input and expected output.

Comment: @kaylum I edited, I would post a picture of how it should look, but I don't know if that's an option.

Comment: use functions for that. Do not code in main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program kind of works.
You have problems marking a particular point in the plane because you starts the loop from `0` rather than from `n` and `-n`. This small adjustment will make your life much easier.
Also think about what the program should do in case of invalid inputs.

About the *cleaner way*, I don't know exactly what you mean, but for sure you can make it easier to read and debug by implementing functions for repetitive tasks.

I show you this program using a function to print a line of the plane, but as you can see the function takes 5 arguments and in `main` there are repeating patterns, these are sign that the program may need some new function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAline( int n, int x, char c, char m, int b );

int main() {

    int i, x = -3, y = 5, n = 9;
    
    for( i = -n; i++; ) putchar( ' ' );
    puts(" ^");
    
    for(i = n; i >= -n; i--) {
        
        if( i ) {
            
            putchar( ' ' );
            printAline( n, x, ' ', '|', i == y );
            puts("");
        }
        
        else {
            
            putchar( '<' );
            printAline( n, x, '-', '+', i == y );
            puts(">");
        }
    }
    
    for( i = -n; i++; ) putchar( ' ' );
    puts(" v");
    
    return 0;
}

void printAline( int n, int x, char c, char m, int b )
{
    for(int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
    
        if( b ) {
            
            i == x ? putchar( 'X' ) : i ? putchar( c ) : putchar( m );
        }
        else {

            i ? putchar( c ) : putchar( m );
        }
    }
}
```

I am sorry for the short variable names: `c` is the main character printed in a line, `m` is the character printed in the middle of the line and `b` is a *bool* used to tell to the function wether the line to print matches the `y` coordinate took from the user (actually hardcoded here).

Edit:
Here's the function slightly modified to avoid the spaces after the y axis in the lines not matching the `y` took from the user. However notice that the function takes 6 arguments, that's a sign that it's probably doing to much things. You could split it up in more functions doing simple tasks, in this way your program well be easier to understand and to work with.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAline( int n, int r, int x, int y, char c, char m );

int main() {

    int i, x = 3, y = -5, n = 9;
    
    for( i = -n; i++; ) putchar( ' ' );
    puts(" ^");
    
    for(i = n; i >= -n; i--) {
        
        if( i ) {
            
            putchar( ' ' );
            printAline( n, i, x, y, ' ', '|' );
            puts("");
        }
        
        else {
            
            putchar( '<' );
            printAline( n, i, x, y, '-', '+' );
            puts(">");
        }
    }
    
    for( i = -n; i++; ) putchar( ' ' );
    puts(" v");
    
    return 0;
}

void printAline( int n, int r, int x, int y, char c, char m )
{
    for(int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
    
        if( r == y ) i == x ? putchar( 'X' ) : i ? putchar( c ) : putchar( m );
        
        else if( i <= 0 || !r ) i ? putchar( c ) : putchar( m );
        
        else return;
    }
}
```

`r` is for row, represents the current line being printed.

Comment: Not a bad approach at all, but you would probably want to double the size of the column output to more closely match the line height. (e.g. outputting `"--"` for each column on the axis instead of `'-'`) You would have to likewise adjust the remaining horizontal positioning. But worth a nod as is.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is way easier and it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but can we use "--" since we used putchar for c(-)? Wouldn't "--" be a string? I'm almost a total begginer  in C, I used python a lot, so for me it kinda doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes it would look much better. The reason why I didn't doubled up the columns is that then is not possible to center the `X` in its coordinate.

Comment: @Enzor you can just swap the `putchar` with a `printf`

Comment: @Davide so, this prints top to bottom chars right? If for example I would like to stop printing blank spaces after the y axis  it would be hard because in case my "x" is on the right side of y axis it wouldn't print correctly? Am I right?

Comment: @Enzor this function doesn't know wether is printing the x axis or just one of the the other common lines, so if you avoid the soaces after the y axis (exept in the line matching the `y` from the user) you would do what you want but ending up with a shorter x axis. I made another function, (check the edit) but I strongly suggest you to make your own functions. Make more than one, each function should do a simple task, like printing only one space in a loop.

Comment: @Enzor I just came back to read the second code and noticed that I was confused, I remade it. [Here](https://tio.run/##pVLbaoNAEH3frzi1D1XUEih9aL2U/kWfCmE1zYKuYdWQEP12O6Mm1UohpCvsrHM9nDPS/5Ky6@6VllmdpAjLKlHF4zYWYl@oBDujdPWeKZ3aoBe01xszmMNgjh7kdm0gR5vDCYTgSL5W2nZwEgJ02KM8HBDhycORjP/sQZN9CfqE/toUhmZxUAdQrhvAwa6uuLONB/qcIZl8pW3h03J@FXMtlyIee/g@Q8B4Lg@14TnT0Cw8zljMvcQm1DAtHtNBVFAqXc0yv8drTbztElOalel1gMLrAfkMyP0DULxE1N4sxn4mhkmr2misAtH@c53E6UddXqIzIISD1K57lnGmrkEU0Z45XBDR3r1NsH8QdrxSZOKUvevym08Zm0s07A5NX6FpcGf6GTd1GkgKRuLbrvsG "C (gcc) – Try It Online") you can check the spaces.

Comment: @Davide haha thank you, I figured it on my own but thank you for your effort!  I couldn't have done it without you.